# How to quit or exit slave JWindow that was created from a master JWindow in Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

How can i exit only they new MainGame that i created from Main? 
Where Main is having an original layer of game. And the MainGame was a dialog window (such as modal windows).

Main.java: (main code)

```
public class Main extends JWindow
{
  private static JWindow j;
  public static MainGame mp;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
        new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {
          public void run()
          {            
            mp = new MainGame(); 
            mp.runit();            
            //mp.stopit();
          }
        }).start();

        j = new Main();
        j.setVisible(true);             
  }
}
```

MainGame.java: (this was extended by Main, and i would like to quite this only).

```
public class MainGame extends JWindow 
{
  private static JWindow j;
  public MainGame()
  { 
    // some GUI ... 
  }

  public static void runit()
  {
    j = new MainGame();
    j.setVisible();

  }
}
```

Comment: What's with all the static variables? Why not just swap views via a CardLayout? Also, do you take care to run your Swing code on the EDT?

Comment: You are abusing the usage of the 'static' keyword. Anyways, first: The method I think is suppose to public static void main, not public static void Main. Second, within your thread where you are creating MainGame, you have access to 'j' (being the static variable), call j.setVisible(false) to hide the window. Third, you can pass the reference of parent JWindow to the other class so that once the other class initializes itself, it call jWindow.setVisibile(false). Hope this helps.

Comment: @Usman Saleem: MainGame visible set to false is not helping a lot. Because in the popup i have a 3D Movie playing as presentation, so i want to shutdown that jWindow dialog box completely so that later i can replay a new one.

Comment: @LearnFedora I was talking about setting 'Main' setVisible to false. You can pass a reference of Main to MainGame constructor. It adds hard dependency, but it will serve your purpose.

Comment: You need to redesign your code, its all messed up (my honest opinion). You should not attempt to recreate MainGame from within MainGame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) better would be implements [CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), as create `Top-Level Container` for new `Window`, then you'll only to switch betweens Cards

2) don't create lots of `Top-Level Container` on Runtime, because there are still in JVM memory untill current instance exist,

- create required number of and re-use that, to avoiding possible memory lacks
- then you have to call `setVisible(false)` and `setVisible(true)`
- `JWindow` missed methods for setting `setDefaultCloseOperation(Whatever);`

3) if you'll create constructor [public JWindow(Frame owner)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JWindow.html#JWindow%28java.awt.Frame%29), then you'll call directly

[SwingUtilities.getAccessibleChildrenCount()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getAccessibleChildrenCount%28java.awt.Component%29) and [SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getWindowAncestor%28java.awt.Component%29)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Testing {

    private JFrame f = new JFrame("Main Frame");
    private JWindow splashScreen = new JWindow();

    public Testing() {
        splashScreen = new JWindow(f);
        splashScreen.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Splash Screen");
        label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(96f));
        splashScreen.getContentPane().add(label, new GridBagConstraints());
        splashScreen.pack();
        splashScreen.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        splashScreen.setVisible(true);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                readDatabase();
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        createAndShowGUI();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void readDatabase() {
        //simulate time to read/load data - 10 seconds?
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void createAndShowGUI() {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("My Frame");
        label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(96f));
        f.add(label);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("JFrame getAccessibleChildrenCount count -> "
                + SwingUtilities.getAccessibleChildrenCount(f));
        System.out.println("JWindow getParent -> "
                + SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(splashScreen));
        splashScreen.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Testing t = new Testing();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not go really into your design. but there is 'j.dispose();'.
this should work. [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29) is the java documentation.

notice:

- dispose(); - deletes the window from memory.
- setVisibilty(false); - just hides it from the screen.
- You can override the 'dispose()' function to do some stuff while the widow is closing (updating scores if its a game) but at the end of the overriden function you have to call 'super.dispose();' so the function of the class Window is called.

Comment: j.dispose() distroyed Main class too.

Comment: then may be mp.dispose(); . Any window you want to dispose. call on it the function. it can be from inside it, like this: this.dispose(); or from another class that holds a reference to the window you want to destroy and call: windowObject.dispose();

Comment: mp.dispose(); does nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

> And the MainGame was a dialog window

But thats not what your code uses. You use a JWindow.

You should be using a JDialog for a modal window. Then you just dispose() the window.

Comment: I tried JDialog, but it keeps the window bar. I can not use BORDERLESS JDialog? (Like i can with JWindow).

Comment: You can still use a JDialog, just use an undecorated dialog. Check out the API for the exact method to use.